# How can I get the vertex coordinates of cow.osg?

Tags: openscenegraph

I want to get the vertex coordinates for the famous model cow.osg in OpenSceneGraph and do some operations with those coordinates. How do I get the coordinates.

Comment: In the sources, there are several examples. Check them and you will find how to get/set the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the coordinates you could just open the file in any text editor. The `.osg` format as well as the newer `.osgt` format is pure text formated files.

When you have opened the file you can find the vertex coordinates under the tag `VertexArray` with all the vertex data contained inside the `{}`  brackets. In the same way the Normals are stored under `NormalArray`. Texture coordinates under `TexCoordArray` etc...